# How to search only on certain region of window on SikuliX

Tags: jython, sikuli

I have monitor with 4k resolution, the animated window that need to be captured only 1024x768 (1/6 of the monitor screen), i want sikuli only search on that window only, not the whole screen because it's lagging. Is there function to do that?

Comment: You using Sikuli with Java or Jython?

Comment: i use Jython (one on the SikuliX IDE) @EugeneS

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to achieve the same result but the most straight forward solution would probably be something like this:

```
leftHalfScreen = Region(0, 0, getScreen().getBounds().width/2, getScreen().getBounds().height)
leftHalfScreen.highlight(1)
```

Based on that example you can change the numbers to obtain the region you need.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene has mentioned above, you need to create an object of Region with the bounds set. Once that is done, you can use click, find, etc for the region using the object and get it done.